React Query - query with values of staleTime and cacheTime refetch api
I have defined


 export const ReactQueryConfig: QueryClientConfig = {   
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            retryOnMount: false,
            refetchOnMount: false, // Prevent refetch when navigating back
            refetchOnReconnect: false,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            retry: 0,
            staleTime: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minutes
            cacheTime:  10 * 60 * 1000 //default 10 minutes
        }
    } };



and I defined my queryClient in getServerSideProps function (ssr) as

const queryClient = new QueryClient(ReactQueryConfig);

but when I go to another page and back to this page in a minute even when my query is fresh in "ReactQueryDevtools" but refetch the api .(react-query V3) this query just call in ssr

